# Solving limits question

Tags: calculus, limits

Use the alternate definition, $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\to a }\frac{f(x) -f(a)}{x - a}$, to determine the instantaneous rate of $f(x) = 4x^2 - 6$ at the point $(3, 30)$.

Comment: I saw another one of your questions. You ask the questions, but provide no work of your own, and even when you are given help, you still ask others what the answer is. This place isn't supposed to be a place where you get people to solve your exercises for you. At least provide some examples of work, or, if you haven't worked anything, some of your own thoughts on how you might solve it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:   $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac{4x^2-6-(4a^2-6)}{x-a}=4(x+a)\quad  \text{ if }x\ne a$$

and $$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ $x\to a\implies x\ne a$